# Query with an array of likes in Doctrine & Symfony 2.1

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, dql

I have an array of terms that I would like to match using the LIKE wildcard in one Doctrine 2 query. The database is SQL and I'm using DQL but a query builder solution would be fine.
My current query setup is this:

```
foreach($textterms as $text)
{
$parameters[] = '%-'.$text.'-%';
}

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
'SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.searchfield IN LIKE (:text) ORDER BY p.datetime DESC'
        )->setParameter('text', $parameters);
        $posts = $query->getResult();
```

But I get the symfony error
    "QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 62: Error: Expected Literal, got '('"

Is this query possible in doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving such error because query is expecting a value after LIKE statement. There is no such a thing like "IN LIKE". Possible solutions which I would consider:

```
// Query Builder added to show difference in code readability I personally use queryBuilder mostly
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('p')
        ->from('Post', 'p')
        ->orderBy('p.datetime', 'DESC');
$i = 0;
$parameters = array();
foreach ($textterms as $key => $text)
{
    $query->orWhere('p.searchfield LIKE ?' . $i++);
    $parameters[] = '%-' . $text . '-%';
}
$query->setParameters($parameters);
$posts = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

// Query
$orX = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Orx();
$i = 0;
$parameters = array();
foreach ($textterms as $text)
{
    $orX->add('p.searchfield LIKE ?' . $i++);
    $parameters[] = '%-' . $text . '-%';
}
$orX = (string)$orX;
if(!empty($orX))
{
    $orX = 'WHERE ' . $orX;
}
$sql = sprintf('SELECT p FROM Post p %s ORDER BY p.datetime DESC', $orX);
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery($sql);
$query->setParameters($parameters);
$posts = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Hi, I played with your query builder solution    foreach ($texterms as $text){$query->orWhere('p.searchfield LIKE ?'.$i++ );$parameters[] = '%-' . $text . '-%';}
But for some reason nothing is put in the posts array even though the query seems to go through in the symfony logger.

Comment: I can't find how ->setparameters is meant to work. Is there meant to be an array of key=>values? When I try $parameters[i] = '%-' . $text . '-%'; I get the error "Invalid parameter: token 15 is not defined in the query. " Thanks for your help

Comment: [A bit more clear example of setParameters usage](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query) if you're using `$parameters[$i]` keep in mind that I'm already doing `$i++` right before value is added to `$parameters`, in case where you get an error it's most likely due to using ?14 in where while doing `$parameters[15] = value;` to the array.
For debugging purposes try at the end do `echo $query->getQuery()->getSQL();` and `var_dump($parameters);`

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's made it clearer. So I moved the $i++ to before the query->orWhere() and now there is no error but still the posts array is not filled. Printing out the sql query shows lots of"...OR p0_.searchfield LIKE ? OR p0_.searchfield LIKE ? OR p0_.searchfield LIKE ? OR p0_.searchfield LIKE ? ORDER BY...". There are no $i numbers in the query, is this normal?.

Comment: Yes it is normal while dumping the SQL. Just put your `$parameters` values in there and try out in phpmyadmin or whatever you're using.